# Little Oh Pee calculus and event with probability going to zero

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ such that $P(X_n = 0) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Is it true that $X_n = o_p(n^k)$, for any $k$?

If so, when discussing convergence in probability and distribution (at any rate), we can ignore events that have probability going to zero of happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $N$ such that for $n > N$, we have

$P(X_n \ne 0) < \varepsilon$.

But, we have, for $n > N$,

$P(a_n|X_n| \geq \delta) \leq P(X_n \ne 0) < \varepsilon$

Hence, regardless of $a_n$ and $\delta$, for any $\varepsilon$ we can find a $N$ such that $n > N$ implies

$P(a_n|X_n| \geq \delta) < \varepsilon$

which proves the result.